# Covariant derivative (or connection) of and along a curve

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, covariance

Let $c:[a,b] \rightarrow M$ be a curve parametrized by arc-length.

Then $c': [a,b] \rightarrow TM$ such that $c'(t) \in T_{c(t)}(M).$

So essentially, I want to understand how $\nabla_{c'}c'$ is defined then in coordinates.

Cause normally, we are dealing with vector fields $X : M \rightarrow TM$ when we talk about the covariant derivative or connection.

In this case, we have for $X,Y: M \rightarrow TM$ that $X= \sum_{i} \eta^i \partial_i$ and $Y = \sum_{i} \zeta^i \partial_i$

In this case,

$$\nabla_YX = \sum_{i,j,k} \zeta^i( \eta^j \Gamma_{i,j}^k \partial_k + \partial_i \eta^j \partial_j)$$

and everything is well-defined.

The problem occurs, cause $c' : [a,b] \rightarrow TM$ so there is no way we can take a partial derivative in some coordinate direction of $c',$
as it just depends on time. Is there still a way to explain how $\nabla_c'c'$ is for example defined, although $c'$ is not really a vector field?

Comment: Here is one way: think of $c'$ as a section of the pull-back bundle $c^*TM$ over $[a,b]$. Then $\nabla_c' c'$ can be thought of as the derivative of $c'$ in the time direction: $(c^*\nabla)_{d/dt} c'$.

Comment: You can also extend the vector field "trivially" within a coordinate patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Write $c'(t) = \sum\limits_i a^i(t)\partial_i\big|_{c(t)}$. Then recall that for any vector field $X$ we can compute $\nabla_{c'}X = \dfrac D{dt}(X\circ c)(t)$.

Comment: but isn't this exactly the question of the TES, that the derivative $\partial_j a^i$ (which would appear in the coordinate representation of the connection) is not defined?

Comment: I thought about this hint and don't understand it, actually. If you say that $\nabla_{c'}X(t) := (X \circ c)'(t)$ then the problem seems to be that the right-hand side is not defined on a general manifold, as we don't know how the time-derivative is defined on the manifold or am I missunderstand your notation?

Comment: @RealAnalysis: You don't misunderstand the notation, but you need to think about the chain rule on a manifold.

Answer (score 2):

Actually a very easy but nice way to see this is to assume first that $c'$ is extended smoothly to a vector field $X$. Now like you already wrote locally $X = \sum_i X^i \partial_i$ and$$\nabla_X X = \sum_k (X(X^k) + \sum_{i,j}X^{i}X^j \Gamma^k_{ij})\, \partial_k$$
To get $\nabla_{c'}c'$ we only need to evaluate $\nabla_X X$ along $c$, which is straight forward except for $X(X^k)$. Therefore we calculate (using a chart $x = (x^1,\dots,x^n))$: $$X_{c(t)}(X^k) = \frac{d}{d \tau}\bigg{\rvert}_{t}( X^k \circ c)(\tau) = \frac{d}{d \tau}\bigg{\rvert}_{t} (X(x^k) \circ c)(\tau) = \frac{d}{d \tau}\bigg{\rvert}_{t} X_{c(\tau)}(x^k) \\ = \frac{d}{d \tau}\bigg{\rvert}_{t} \frac{d}{d s}\bigg{\rvert}_\tau (x^k \circ c)(s) = {(x^k \circ c)}''(t)$$
Here I simply used that $X$ is tangent along $c$. Moreover this calculation shows that we only need to know $X$ along $c$, that is $c'$. Therefore $\nabla_{c'} c' $ is well defined along $c$ and by the above formula (writing $c_j = x^j \circ c$):

$$\nabla_{c'} c' = \sum_k (c_j'' + \sum_{i,j}c_i'c_j' \Gamma^k_{ij})\, \partial_k $$